# Is there another way except /etc/passwd to get users shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to find all users on the server using some kind of shell. For example I want to get count of users with /bin/csh on logon. But I don't have any permission to /etc/passwd file. The command getent also doesn't work. Is there some possible solution for my problem?

Comment: `/etc/passwd` is supposed to be world-readable for just this kind of reason (it's why all the actually confidential bits moved to `/etc/shadow`).

Comment: How can you be given this kind of task and then not even read-only access to /etc/passwd ?

Comment: that said, this depends entirely on your server; many systems will have tools like `getent`; you need to specify your operating system to make this answerable.

Comment: ...arguably, it's not a programming question at all, unless you're looking for (say) a C API to use.

Comment: Actually -- you ask in a programming forum, I give you a programming answer; getpwent it is (because if you **didn't** want to know how to do this programatically, it would be off-topic). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** A standard API call is available to retrieve `/etc/passwd` entries, which can be configured to retrieve them from sources other than `/etc/passwd` (should your system's NSS configuration be appropriate). From [`man 3 getpwent`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwent):

> ```
> #include <sys/types.h>
> #include <pwd.h>
> struct passwd *getpwent(void);
> ```
>
> The getpwent() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-out fields of a record from the password database (e.g., the local password file /etc/passwd, NIS, and LDAP). The first time getpwent() is called, it returns the first entry; thereafter, it returns successive entries.

If you're doing this on Linux (or another operating system with a similar NSS stack) and want a command-line tool, I'd suggest [`getent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent):

```
$ getent passwd username
username:x:1000:1000::/home/cduffy:/bin/bash
```

...then, to extract only the shell:

```
$ IFS=: read username _ uid gid _ homedir shell _ < <(getent passwd username)
$ print '%s\n' "$shell"
/bin/bash
```

---

If you want a tool calling `getpwent()` without using `getent`, consider `perl`. Quoting from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_getpwent.htm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(($name, $passwd, $uid, $gid, $quota,
  $comment, $gcos, $dir, $shell) = getpwent()){
   print "Name = $name\n";
   print "Password = $passwd\n";
   print "UID = $uid\n";
   print "GID = $gid\n";
   print "Quota = $quota\n";
   print "Comment = $comment\n";
   print "Gcos = $gcos\n";
   print "HOME DIR = $dir\n";
   print "Shell = $shell\n";
}
```

---

By the way: It's extremely unconventional for `/etc/passwd` not to be world-readable; confidential information has been moved from there to `/etc/shadow` for decades. If `getent` is installed but fails with an error when run, your NSS stack is probably configured to expect a readable `/etc/passwd`, and whichever administrator or script modified it to break that constraint thus broke your operating system.

Comment: Hmm. The question states that "gentent" does not work.

Comment: @Thilo, ...added a perl implementation. If that doesn't work, the system is simply broken and needs to be fixed. (Conceivably, the canonical datasource could be NIS, LDAP, YP, or otherwise something other than `/etc/passwd` -- so not having access to the file isn't necessarily fatal to `getpwent()`'s correct operation).